# How to access to the public synonym when there's another object with the same name in current schema?

Tags: oracle, synonym

Someone creates a public synonym for me to access, but I already has a table which has the same name as that public synonym. How can I access to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "PUBLIC" as the schema name, and the quotation marks are required.

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work and raises error ORA-00903: invalid table name

Comment: then you need to give more information about your Oracle schema / table name / synonym name...

Comment: ok, I tried in the sample schema "scott" and I create another schema "john". I create a public synonym "s_emp" points to table "emp". After the priviliege assignment, I can access "s_emp" from schema "john". Then I create a table "s_emp" in schema "john".

Comment: I don't really understand... how did you make the synonym ? how did you assign the priviliges ???

Comment: I create the public synonym under "scott": "create public synonym s_emp for emp" and "grant select on emp to john", then "john" can access it via "s_emp".

Comment: that was possible in earlier Oracle version though bad design... no it is no more possible... for name resolution Oracle uses the following rules - see http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/sql_elements009.htm

Comment: I got the answer thru the doc you offered, I should use "PUBLIC", and quotation marks are required. thx for the replies.